# jQuery show/hide div with select options by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, show-hide

I am having problem with showing/hiding my divs, which depent on selected value "name".

Here is my HTML :

```
    <select name="selectVehicle" id="selectVehicle">
    <option name="A" value="A">Car</option>
    <option name="C" value="C">Truck</option>
    </select>
    <div id="A" class="vehicle">+Car+</div>
    <div id="C" class="vehicle" style="display:none;">+Truck+</div>
```

...And my JS:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#selectVehicle').change(function(){
            $('.vehicle').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wgee7ekh/1/

Comment: what's the problem that you are facing??

Comment: Now it selects them from value but I would like to be selected by name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you select based on the `name` attribute:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectVehicle').change(function(){
        $('.vehicle').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('name')).show();
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nku89k6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:selected` to get the `name` property of selected option.

```
$('#selectVehicle').change(function(){
    $('.vehicle').hide();
    $('#' + $(':selected',this).attr('name')).show();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgee7ekh/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `this` in your `.change()` event handler is the `<select>` element, not the selected `<option>` element, but you want the `name` attribute from the selected `<option>` element.

You can get the selected option in a couple ways.  In plain Javascript, you can use the `.options` array and the `.selectedIndex` property as in `this.options[this.selectedIndex]` to get it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectVehicle').change(function(){
        $('.vehicle').hide();
        $('#' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("name")).show();
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/upswtfeg/

or in jQuery, you can use the pseudo-selector `:selected` to find it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectVehicle').change(function(){
        $('.vehicle').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('name')).show();
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ywkd25w8/

Comment: Could you please explain to me how to achieve that with the div id ?

Comment: @GabrielDichev - I don't understand what you're asking.  I've included a working jsFiddle demo for both blocks of code so it should be clear how they are working.  Both examples are using the div id.  Are you now asking to do something different?

Comment: I still can't understand why this answer was voted down. I see two correct examples of how it can be done. I see explanation, which is not usual phenomenon in SO. So what it is wrong?

Comment: I didn't vote it down but I already had the answer before that. Instead of the select option by name I would like to be by the HTML tag ID .

Comment: @GabrielDichev - that doesn't make sense.  The `<option>` elements in your HTML don't have any IDs.  Just like the answer you already put the green checkmark by, this gets the `name` attribute from the `<option>` element and then uses that as an ID value to show the proper div.

Comment: @GabrielDichev -  It's also relevant that SO isn't just a race to the first one that shows working code, but rather to write the "best overall answer".  Most people agree that an answer that explains what is going on is better than one that just offers working code with little explanation. That's what I tried to do and I thought it even more informative if I showed how it works in plain Javascript too. You're free to select whichever answer you want as your favorite, but I thought I'd explain why I posted my answer. I am also baffled by the downvote. I use downvotes for answers that are wrong.